# Allow high rep users to edit other SE answers/questions

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits

At the moment, users with 200+ reputation on one SE site get an automatic 100 rep bonus on any SE sites where they have a profile. This allows all the basic privileges like flagging, voting up, and participating in Meta.

On a particular SE site, a user has to obtain 2,000 reputation before they can edit questions and answers without getting them approved. This is a *long* way from the 101 starting reputation.

**Proposal A**: That users with a high amount of reputation, perhaps 5,000 (maybe higher) on one SE site, receive the ability to edit questions and answers on *any Stack Exchange Q&A* that they're signed up on without getting them approved by others.

**Proposal B**: If proposal A is not acceptable, another option is to lower the reputation required to edit for high rep users on one site. This would mean if I have over 5k (or 10k or whatever we decide on), then I only have to get something like 300 or 500 reputation on any one SE site before I can edit without going through the queue. This would force the users to be around longer so that they know the community more, but still be much easier to obtain than 2,000.

I am *NOT* proposing that high reputation users get 2,000 reputation on every SE site they have a profile on.

Editing to improve the quality doesn't usually require knowledge of the subject matter and, as these are the most common and necessary edits, shouldn't be required to be approved if the user already has proven themselves to be non-malicious on one SE site.

This will reduce some of the load on the review queues, allow smaller SE sites to be better moderated by non-regulars, and, most importantly, allow for more higher quality content with less delay.

Answer (score 23):

Bad idea.

By getting to 2000 rep on a site, you show that you are familiar with the community and its standards. You know something about them (and hopefully the topic).

That doesn't automatically translate to knowledge of other topics and communities within the network.

That's the reason you should earn the rep on a site in order to participate in the higher moderation facilities of the site.

Comment: I understand this approach for all privileges besides editing. Editing is almost always formatting changes, not something related to the actual content of the site. It doesn't usually require knowledge of the subject material

Comment: Do you have statistics to back up that claim? And how do you know that's true for sites you have never participated in?

Comment: I'd love to see some statistics to prove the claim wrong :)

Comment: @ZachSaucier I think you're probably right that most edits are benign. However, I don't see wanting to get around having to suggest a formatting edit as a compelling enough reason to introduce a one-off special case in how privileges work across the network. The suggested edit review queue is pretty much never backlogged even on the smaller sites (and if it is, the site has bigger problems), so that's a non-issue.

Comment: [Peter](http://stackexchange.com/users/24885/peter-mortensen?tab=activity) still needs review queue approval for edits on many sites.  (Side bit, I would be in favor of a special "This is Peter" flag for reviewless editing across all network sites).

Comment: @MichaelT: Not to forget that Peter would have much less reputation, if it weren’t for reputation through edits.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I dread the day I ever see a 'bad edit' audit with Peter's icon in it.

Comment: I disagree. Most of my edits suggestions fix formatting and grammar. On Beta sites, moderators get easily overwhelmed by the suggestions. If they're dedicated enough, this will hurt their personal life.

Comment: @TomášZato: Can you back up that claim in any way? Reviewing suggested edits is fast and can be done by a lot of people. I usually see only a handful of suggested edits on all sites, on which I can review edits, taken together. Even on Stack Overflow, this queue isn’t a problem.

Answer (score 13):

> Editing to improve the quality doesn't usually require knowledge of the subject matter

I don't find this to be true.

But putting that aside, each site forms a community that is as individual as the subjects themselves are.  Outsiders to that community are very much that - outsiders. If you can't put in the time to demonstrate that you are a full contributer, then why should they allow you to edit their contributions?

The rep score isn't meant to measure expertise, or useless participation, but *valued* participation.

Further, each site is different in how quickly a user can accrue reputation. Someone spending significant time on a slow site to slowly grow their reputation shouldn't have to wonder why they spent all that time when others are getting their reputation elsewhere and wielding powers that weren't earned in this community.

If you want to edit a site, start making edits, and let others approve them.  You will gain reputation as a result, and if you choose to further help the community you'll eventually gain the reputation to skip the approval process.

Until then, if you don't earn it on a given site, you don't get it.

Comment: If somebody needs to be convinced of this point, I suggest that they review a bunch of firsts posts from users with association bonus. Yes, they are on average less worse than first posts by full newbies, but still you get one that has problems stemming from fundamental misconceptions surprisingly often – and yes, even from users with thousands of reputation on other sites.

Answer (score 8):

The time it takes to earn 2,000 rep on a site provides the much need ***getting-acquainted* time** you need with a community before you take your place as a full-fledged "editor" of that site. Communities each develop their own customs and their own characteristics based what *works* for them.

But what you *don't* want is a situation where 5,000+ reputation denizens drop into a community and *de facto* tell everybody that they're all doing it wrong based on what a community decided *elsewhere.*

What works on one site may not reflect the traditions and practices of another. But every community has to figure out what works for them, and **the cost of admission for taking on the leadership roles in a community is that time you spend learning how each neighborhood works for yourself.**

Comment: Indeed. In practice the reputation score is actually a score for inertia and time spent on a given stack; as by the time you have a high reputation/inertia score, almost nothing will bring it down. And so it doesn't reflect correctly one's conduct on a given stack but rather their commitment to that stack's culture.

Answer (score 6):

I could see maybe 500 or 1k rep rather than the standard 100 rep. But I don't know I'd go so far as to recommend 2k rep to a new user.

I'll be the first to stand up and tout my ignorance in a new community, so it seems unfair and haphazard to grant even myself 2k rep to start.

Just because I know one topic/community very well, that doesn't automatically translate to knowing all SE communities.

So, while I agree more than 100rep would be nice if a user has passed the 5 figure mark on another site, I think 2K is just too much.

Comment: To clarify, are you suggesting that the reputation required to edit without going through the queue should be lower for high reputation SE users OR are you suggesting the starting reputation should be higher that 101?

Comment: No. I would not begin to open the can of worms that is rep as it relates to privileges. I'm suggesting perhaps more initial rep for 5-figure users, but leave the rep<>privileges the same.